# C Programming - using modulo of a sum of unsigned integers which overflows

Tags: c, overflow, modulo, unsigned-integer

I have an assignment in University, where I need to write functions for a given main program. 
It is all in c.

So, my problem is that I need to use the module of a sum of two unsigned integers.

```
uint32_t mod_add(uint32_t x, uint32_t y, uint32_t n)
{
    uint32_t res;

    res = (x + y) % n;
```

This works fine, when  sum of x and y is below 2^32-1.
My trouble is that when the sum is above this value, it obviously overflows and the modulo value is wrong.

In my assignment x = 2^32-3; y =1174501 and n =2^32-1 (n is the modulo);
My result is 1174497, it should be 1174499.

Anybody any idea, how to solve this?

Comment: try `res=((uint64_t)x+y)%n;` instead of.

Comment: yeah.... not allowed to use 64bit... thats the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you are.

```
uint32_t remainder(uint32_t x, uint32_t y, uint32_t d)
{
    uint32_t r1 = x % d;
    uint32_t r2 = y % d;

    return r1 < (d - r2) ? r1 + r2 : r1 - (d - r2);
}
```

Of course instead of `uint32_t` you can use any integer type as for example `unsigned long long`.

Comment: Maybe `(r1 + r2) < d ? r1 + r2 : (r1 + r2) - d` would be more readable. Nice answer anyway.

Comment: @izlin r1 + r2 can result in overflow. So you will deal with the same original problem.

Comment: @ Vlad, what would happen, if the task would be (x-y)%d now?

Comment: @DavidHenkel Just subtract the smaller from the greater.